# Align text at left but also at center of my div

Tags: html, css, alignment

Im trying to align some links at center of my div, but I also want that text of my links are aligned at left.

But Im not having sucess doing this, I am able to align to the left or to the center but not both simultaneously.

Do you know how we can do this?

Here I have demonstration of what Im getting: http://jsfiddle.net/HRKN4/

I have this html:

```
<div  class="container">
    <h3>Title:</h3>
    <div class="content">
       <ul class="links">
          <li> <a  href="#">&raquo;&raquo; This link is bigger</a></li>
          <li> <a  href="#">&raquo;&raquo; Smaller 1</a></li>
          <li> <a  href="#">&raquo;&raquo; link 1</a></li> 
       </ul>
     </div>
</div>
```

And this CSS:

```
.container
{
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
    background:pink;
}

.content
{
    width:100%;
    height:300px;
}

.links 
{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0 auto; 
}

.links li a 
{
    text-decoration:none;
    background:red;
    color:#000;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin:0 auto; 
}
```

Comment: So you want the list of links in the center of the div but all of the link's text left aligned?

Comment: Yes...it is what Im trying to do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use table layout :

```
.links {
   display:table;
}
```

And

```
.links li a {
   display:table-row;
}
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/HRKN4/2/)

Or just

```
.links li{
    text-align : left;
}
```

Instead of `display:table-row;`

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/HRKN4/19/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Notulysses, in your fiddle is working fine, but on my example I dont understand why its not working, just works if I change .links li a {display:table-row} to .links li a {text-align:left;} and keeping .links{display:table}

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a width for the "content" div and then center it using `margin:0 auto;` that way you can still use `text-align:left;` to left-align the text within the div while still keeping the div centered on the document.

[Here is an updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HRKN4/1/)

Comment: Actually go with @Notulysses answer, that way you don't have to set a static width on the content div.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
.links 
{
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0 auto; 
    text-align: left;
}
```

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/m9daD/

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
.links 
{
    list-style-type:none;
    width:50%;
    float:right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HRKN4/17/

Answer (score 1):

If you set `..containerlinks` to `display:inline-block;` and `text-align:center;` it should be enough.

`ul` will take the width of the longest link and will be centered from `text-align:center;`
All links can be aligned left inside it .

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HRKN4/21/)**

---

```
.container {
    text-align:center;
    background:pink;
}
.content {
}
.links {
    list-style-type:none;
    display:inline-block;/* as an inline boxe it will centered from text align on .container */
    text-align:left;/* content will be aligned towards left */
}
.links li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    background:red;
    color:#000;
}
```